# IQueryable OrderBy/GroupBy Regex

Tags: c#, regex, split, group-by, iqueryable

I have an IQueryable result with names that looks something like this:

```
100lbs
10pts
150lbs
11pts
15pt
10pt
```

I'd like to group the results by the trailing letters so the results look more like this:

```
100lbs
150lbs
10pt
15pt
10pts
11pts
```

Is it possible/how could I use a Regex to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the `IQuerable` provider?  I doubt EF / NHibernate would support something that complex.

Comment: need a bit more information.  Is your IQuerable in Memory (Linq2Objects) or is it from LinqToSQL, or LinqToEntities?

Comment: You should also think about having `10` and `lbs` in separate columns.

Comment: Its Linq-to-Entities. I agree separate columns would be a better design unfortunately I've inherited this.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what your linq stetement looks like but what you can try to do is to create a fake varaible just for sorting

somethink like

```
var result =
    (from c in db.Table 
     select new 
     {
         mainresult = c.mainresult, 
         tempresult ==c.mainresult,

     }
    ).ToList().Select(c=>new{
      mainresult = c.mainresult, 
      tempresult=new string(c.mainresult
             .Where(!char.IsDigit).ToArray())})
    .OrderBy(c=>c.tempresult)
    .Select(c=>c.mainresult)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You can't do `.Where(!char.IsDigit)`.

Comment: Why because it Querable?

Comment: Because `Operator ! cannot be applied to operand of type 'method group'`. You want `.Where(x => !char.IsDigit(x))`.

Comment: @gunr2171 And of course *that* likely won't be able to be understood by the query provider, even though that change makes it compile.

Answer (score -1):

```
var list = new List<string>();
            list.Add("100lbs");
            list.Add("10lbs");
            list.Add("10pts");

            var groupings = list.GroupBy((s)=>{
                if (s.EndsWith("lbs"))//you can use regex here 
                {
                    return "lbs";
                }
                else if (s.EndsWith("lbs"))
                {
                    return "pts";
                }
                return "none";
            },s=>s);
            foreach (var item in groupings)
            {
                item.key will have category "lbs"/"pts" 
            }
```

Comment: Remember, this most likely needs to come from a database, which means the query is being ran from Entity Framework or NHibernate. Does sql know what `EndsWith` is?

Comment: I hope this will get you started . use regex in place of EndsWith. You can get results into a saperate list and then process , yes EF/Nhibernate does not know EndsWith or regex either.